# Subdomain to Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite `mysite.com/signup/register` to `signup.mysite.com/register`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^signup.mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/signup/register/%1/$1 [L]
```

when I try `http://signup.mysite.com/register` it shows my default home page (equals `http://www.mysite.com`).

When I try `http://signup.mysite.com/signup/register` it shows page I really want.

**EDIT FOR POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^signup.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/signup/register/$1 [L]
```

This works and shows correct page. But one question: how can I do this without redirect, keeping the subdomain in url?

Answer (score 0):

Hey tryout this one,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^your_dir_name/(.*) http://your_subdomain.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: same problem. only works if I put dirname in url, not just subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

in your routes.php

```
$route['register']='signup/register';
```